# tkinter: highlighting de-highlighting of text using tags

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and I want to implement highlighting and de-highlighting of text using tkinter tags. I tried [tag_remove()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) method but thats erring in my case so I thought to implement highlighting and de-highlighting in this way. I want the text to highlight when I press 'a'on the keyboard, dehighlight when I press 'x', and again highlight when I press 'a'. Is there any way to set the priorities of tags so that my goal is achieved? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Menu
from tkinter import ttk 

class AnnotationTool(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) 

        self.tagA='INGREDIENT'
        self.keyA='a'
        self.results_field = Text(self)
     
        self.results_field.config(height=20,spacing1=5,wrap='word',undo=True)
        self.results_field.grid(pady=10,column=3,row=3,padx=10,rowspan=12)
        self.results_field.insert('insert','abc def ghi')

        self.results_field.focus() 
        self.results_field.tag_configure(self.tagA, background="yellow")
        self.results_field.tag_configure('hide', background="white")

        self.results_field.bind(self.keyA, self.onKeyPressA)
        self.results_field.bind('x', self.onKeyPressX)


    def onKeyPressA(self,event):
        self.results_field.tag_add(self.tagA, 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
        return "break"

    def onKeyPressX(self,event):
        self.results_field.tag_add('hide','sel.first', 'sel.last')
        return "break"
                    


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(AnnotationTool)
        self.title('App')

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.pack_forget()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


def main():
    app=App()
    app.geometry("1300x1000") 
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, use the `tag_raise` method. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_raise-method

Comment: If you want to remove the highlighting, `tag_remove` is the way to do it. If it's giving you an error, please show the error.

Comment: Its not giving an error per se, but its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag_remove` is the proper way to remove the highlighting. It's not clear if you want to remove only the highlighting at the current position or everywhere. Assuming you only want the highlighting after the insertion point, you can do something like this:

```
tag_range = self.results_field.tag_nextrange(self.tagA, "insert")
if tag_range:
    self.results_field.tag_remove(self.tagA, *tag_range)
```

If you don't want to do that and instead want to stack another tag on top, you can change the priority with `tag_raise`. The following moves the "hide" tag above `self.tagA`:

```
self.results_field.tag_raise("hide", self.tagA)
```